# What is the best practice for using Redux to handle full async services?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-async-actions

I wonder what is the best way to handle an async service using Redux with error, loading, ... and how to implement that?
I am currently using Promise an axios to handle API and call
3 actions request, success and failure:

```
export function requestExample(page = 1, category = "") 
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(get_Request()); //set isLoading = true
        request.get(`/posts/myPosts`).then(
            response => {
                dispatch(get_Success(response.data)); //set isLoading = false, data = payload.data
            }
        ).catch(error=>{dispatch(get_Failure())}) //set isLoading = false, data = []
    }
}
```

My response shape object:

```
{data: [], isLoading: false}
```

some time I use:

```
{data: [], isLoading: false, isLoadDone: false}
```

I handle error by using axios intercepter when create instance of axios, and stack all my error and show them as modal when they happened.

```
request.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

request.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response;
  },
  error => {
    if (error.status !== 200)
      store.dispatch(openModal("alert", { title: "Lỗi", text: `Error code: ${error.status} <br> Error content: ${error.statusText} `, type: "Fail" }));
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

I want some comments about my structure and know more about another way to handle async service with better performance and memory. Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at Redux Toolkit? Check out [`createAsyncThunk()`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk).

Comment: Thank Mike, I haven't ever known about Redux Toolkit before. I will research now :D

Comment: See also: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

Comment: @DongNguyenVan Page and category are part of a query so you should save that as something like: `{dataType: {'page=1&category=one':{loading, requested, error, stale, refreshing, data}}}` where data is an array of id's and `page=1&category=one' is  the query to get the page as string. the items themselves are stored in `{dataType:{data:{1:{loading, requested, error, stale, refreshing, data:{id:1, otherProps}}}}}` I don't think redux toolkit works with server side filtering or sorting or at least they haven't bothered to add an example for that.

Comment: HMR, I don't understand about page and categories in your state. Do you have any document or source code about that?

Comment: @Mike is right, toolkit is amazing. Checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lCmbth63k0&t=57s&ab_channel=JustinKim incase you want to learn toolkit and know more about the advantages it has to offer over redux.